# What is a prana?

Tags: yoga

- Does flora - trees, flowers, earth contain prana?
- Is this a cosmic energy that is set in earth and nature?
- Do living organisms contain that energy?
- Can it heal or give you its power?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagadish_Chandra_Bose

Comment: Prana can be compared to Oxygen, it is a life giving substance which sustains us. Only difference is while Oxygen is limited and is present only in some places (Earth) prana pervades the entire universe. Also oxygen is physical whereas prana is metaphysical :). Prana is sometimes translated as life-air. Great yogis who have realized this no longer are sustained by the five elements but directly by the cosmic energy Prana.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Energy means power, yes trees, flower have them. This energy lasts for some time only. Like when a flower rises its power lasts for 1-2 days, after this time flower or leaves fall. Every thing has its time.

#### what is prana? does flora - trees, flowers, earth contain it?

Prana is there in trees. **Are you asking Prana means "Jeeva"?** If yes then yes trees are considered as living beings.

In `Tulasidaskrut Ramayana` When Lord Rama was asked why he hide himself behind trees and killed Vali? There is mention that those trees were cursed 7 sages who became 7 trees of "Tada" <- I do not know its English name, whom Lord Rama freed by his arrow only!! This means their energy is there. Prana should also be there.

In **Shiva Maha Purana** Mother Parvati converted 4 deities and Guru Brihaspati in trees, on Lord Shiva's advice she freed them too.

Earth is a goddess in Hinduism, so it should be living being I guess, in reality I do not know. :)

In `Varah Puran` Goddess Earth is there whom Lord Vishnu told the importance of Shrimad Bhagwat Geeta.

#### Can it give you power? Is it used for healing?

Also we eat them and we get energy from them. Many plants are used to make medicines, so they are used for healing.

*Disclaimer:I don't understand more about your question, but what I understood I answered. Please tell me if I misunderstood your question. I will either edit or will remove this answer so this page looks clean.*

Answer (score 3):

*Prana* is the life-force energy. One of the things that happens with evolution is the increase in level of Prana. This is enunciated by the concept of *Kalas*:

> ...In those days, it was said that the life or Prana in a stone is equal
>   to one Kala, the water element is said to have two *Kalas*. Fire has
>   three *Kalas*, *Vayu* (Air element) has four, and the Space or *Akash*
>   has five. Plants and trees are said to have six Kalas. Animals have
>   seven *Kalas*. Human beings have eight *Kalas*.
>
> If it is an extraordinary human being then he is said to have nine
>   *Kalas*...

Read more here: http://www.artofliving.org/wisdom-q-a-25-february-2014-qa-5